# WordPress media library not loading when redux framework is activaed

Tags: wordpress, redux-framework

One of my customers is facing an issue with redux framework. When redux framework is activated on his blog, the media library stops loading and shows only loader icons. When redux framework is deactivated, it starts loading again.

Customer is using Redux Framework v3.6.4 and WordPress v4.7.3

Is any of you has the solution for this issue, kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there's an ajax issue based on invalid output. Best to load your Google Chrome console with Redux activated and try and load the media and see what's happening.

More than likely, the way it was coded there's an improper isset() not where it needs to be, and WP_DEBUG is enabled.  ;)